# Correct way to use spread notation when appending an object into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I want to `push()` an object into an array using the spread notation.

I have done this two ways and each have worked, but I would like to know which is the correct way and what the difference between the two are.

```
const arr = [{ id: 1, color: red }, { id: 2, color: blue }] 
const obj = { id: 3, color: green }
```

Method 1:

`[...arr, obj]`

Method 2:

`[...arr, ...obj]`

Both outcomes are giving me

`[{ id: 1, color: red }, { id: 2, color: blue }, { id: 3, color: green }]`

Comment: `[...arr, ...obj]` should give you a ***TypeError: obj is not iterable***

Comment: I cannot get your second approach to work. Can you make a [MCVE], please?

Comment: so only the first should work, but keep in mind that it does not add an element. it creates a new array.

Comment: You are actually creating a new array. If you want it in original array just use push